# Difference between IRR and ROR

Tags: hedge-funds

Most of the clients in financial world refers to two terms **IRR** and **ROR** for the fund and there is a calculation formula for the same.

What is the difference between these two terms and where and why it matters?

Comment: Do you have a specific context that made you use the hedge funds tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be differences in different contexts, but here's my general understanding:

Rate of Return (or Return on Investment) is the total gain or loss of an investment divided by the initial investment amount.  e.g. if you buy stock for $100 and later sell it for $120 you have a 20% Rate of Return.  You would have a 20% ROR *regardless* of if you sell it tomorrow or in a year.

Internal Rate of Return is effectively annualized.  It is the annual rate at which each of a series of cashflows is discounted that would give you a net present value of 0.  Meaning if you spent $100 today and *in exactly one year* you received $120 back, you would have an IRR of 20%.  If you received the $120 back in 6 months, your IRR would be roughly 40%.

An IRR calculation can include *multiple* cashflows at various times, while ROR is (in my mind) the *total* net gain or loss relative to the investment (irrespective of the time of the cash flows).

IRR is more effective when comparing investments that have different time horizons.  Spending $100 to get $120 tomorrow is much better (from an IRR perspective) than getting $120 two years from now, since you could take that $20 gain and invest it for the rest of the two years.